# close instance of excel that does not have workbook associated with?

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have some blank instance of excel opened. I want to be able to close the instances of excel that does not have a workbook associated with it.

```
Public xlsApp As Excel.Application
Public xlsWB As Excel.Workbook

public openExcel()
Try
   Dim path As String
   path = "C:\excel.xlsm"
   xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(path)
   Catch ex As Exception
   My.Application.Log.WriteException(ex, TraceEventType.Error, "Additional information or details")
   Exit Sub
End Try
end sub

   Public Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub

====when run will open one excel, if excel window is close, the instance stays on, you will see the blank excel workbook. I want to close that instance when this sub re runs.
public doThis()
    releaseObject(xlsApp)
    releaseObject(xlsWB)
    openExcel() <<== 
end sub
```

Comment: Did you open the instances with VB.net. If so then you are not quitting it properly. Can you paste some of your code?

Comment: @MichaelZ. recheck post.

Comment: Try unloading all objects like I have to see if your issue persists. I use this exact method and Excel always closes when I close it. Sometimes GC won't run until my app is closed though. You could call GC to speed that up.

Comment: I don't see you calling `xlsApp.Quit()` or `xlsWB.Close()`. You have to close those.

Comment: Why are you releasing your objects before they are used? It goes `Release(object)` then you call `OpenExcel()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Excel to close properly you have to unload all of your COM objects

```
        Dim xl As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application()
        Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = xl.Workbooks.Add()
        Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet = wb.Worksheets.Add()


        wb.Close()
        xl.Quit()
        ReleaseComObject(ws)
        ReleaseComObject(wb)
        ReleaseComObject(xl)
        ws = Nothing
        wb = Nothing
        xl = Nothing
```

If you aren't consuming the Excel instance and you are just displaying it then maybe try this. This will kill the process as soon as it is created so you'll want to put the `p.Kill()` in another place.  Also note that this kills the process so no changes will be saved.

```
Dim p As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path)
p.Kill()
```

Comment: is there a way to close using system.diagnostics?

Comment: You can kill Excel processes with System.Diagnostics, but you won't know if it's your instance. It could be an instance that the user is using. If you have the ProcessID for your instance then you can safely kill it with System.Diagnostics

Comment: What if I'm opening the path using system.diagnostics and closing it after opening. Would I be able to and if so how?

Comment: Yes, assign to a variable like this. `Dim p As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path)` - then call `p.Kill()`. I don't recommend this though.

Comment: Your best bet is to restructure your code to handle the objects properly. If you close them all like I have in the example it should work fine.